# Cant upload a file using PHP?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, save

Can you anyone look at my code? People can click the upload button to upload some file and the code should move it to a new location and save it. I tested it by uploading a image file and I cant find that file in the folder I specified. I am certain the directory is correct because I used directory is folder and it can lead to the folder I want it to be in. Because the dir below has my name, I used "1" instead. Thank you in advance!

I changed the code according to answer but it is still giving me back error: 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/Users/angeloliao/Documents/Screen.tiff): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/JuvoliciousProductViewer/5.php on line 16

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/usr/local/zend/tmp/phpdfCRD3' to '/Users/angeloliao/Documents/Screen.tiff' in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/JuvoliciousProductViewer/5.php on line 16

I tried to change the folder's permission using the following command on terminal: sudo chown -R 0755 /Users/angeloliao/Documents. It ran.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
       <input type="file" name="file" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
   </form>
   <?php
   if ($_FILES) {
       $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
       $dir = "/Users/angeloliao/Documents/";
   if (move_uploaded_file($temp,$dir.$name)) {
       echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
     }
     } else {
         echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
   }
   ?>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not doing any error-checking. Your code should heck for errors and report them. That way you have a fighting chance of diagnosing a problem before posting here. Look at the PHP section [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) - particularly the section on errors - and check the return value of `move_uploaded_file()`.

Comment: Dont forget the trailing slash after `Documents/`, also theres alot missing to make it **safe** or robust from errors

Comment: Id also suggest posting it to a separate page, then redirecting back to clear the Submitted data, no one like multiple uploads, but that's a tiny bit work to explain.

Comment: This is really dangerous. You should never use the provided name of a file for storage on your server. Instead you should use some sort of random number (perhaps hashed). Depending on your php.ini settings (and file permissions), imagine if someone uploaded a file named "../../../usr/local/bin/php". Then they could replace your php interpreter with something that executes malicious code for example.

Comment: + for the dot dot dash ( directory traversal ), listen to @PhpMyCoder

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>
    <?php
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $dir = "/Users/1/Documents/";
        move_uploaded_file($temp,$dir.$name);
    ?>
</body>
```

Should be a _ not + and the directory should be "Documents/" WITH a slash

Answer (score 0):

As per [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), the temporary name is found in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` not `$_FILES['file']['tmp+name']`. Also, do a `var_dump()` of `$dir.$name`. If the file you uploaded is "image.jpg" then it would be `/Users/1/Documentsimage.jpg`. Notice the missing slash.

Changing this will make your code work, but it still doesn't handle all possible errors nor is it secure! Uploads can fail. If they do, you will find an error code ([the docs has a reference that lists them all](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)) in `$_FILES['file']['error']`. You should check that the uploaded succeeded before moving the temporary file (and you should also only execute the move command if the form has been submitted).

In addition, it is not secure to use the name provided by the uploader. Consider if the `$_FILE['file']['name']` was `../../../usr/local/bin/php`. Then the uploader could replace your PHP interpreter with a malicious executable. This is dangerous! Never trust user input! In this case, the best practice is to randomly generate a filename which is not dependent on the original filename (ie. don't just hash the provided filename, because what if two people upload a file with a same name?).

```
if($_POST['submit'] === 'upload') {  // only process form if it has been submitted

    if($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        exit('There was an error uploading your file');
    }

    $uploads_dir = '/Users/1/Documents/';
    $upload_name = sha1(mt_rand().microtime(true)); // you should actually pick
                                                    // something more unique
                                                    // (collisions are possible)

    move_uploaded_file($FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir . $upload_name);
}
```

Comment: ◎PhpMyCoder Please refer to my edited code. It is still not working, error notice(permission denied). I tried to change the folder permission but it does not work

Comment: @Angelo Look over my code again and re-read my answer. You haven't implemented it exactly. The version you updated is still vulnerable. You need to chown the file for the apache user (usually that's www-data, but it's system dependent). You can check by going to your httpd.conf. You could also run `ps aux | grep '(httpd|apache)'` (assuming you're running apache) and check the user.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have another related question. I am using Zend server now and the apache user is "daemon" according to the httpd.conf file. I am developing the website on my own computer now. Which directory should I set the uploaded file to? From a more secured and better practice standpoint.